# How to make JQuery UI work in a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am a COMPLETE beginner at JQuery (and javascript in general) but I'm having a go at this.

Simple setup: Layout contains view, which contains simple JQuery tabs just like http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html.

I have the following haml in layout head:

```
%head
  = javascript_include_tag "jquery", "ui/jquery.ui.core", "ui/jquery.ui.widget", "ui/jquery.ui.tabs"
  = stylesheet_link_tag "global", "profiles", "forms", "smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom", :cache => true
  :javascript
    $(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
```

I have the following haml in my new.html.haml view:

```
#tabs{:class=>"ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"}
  %ul{:class=>"ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"}
    %li
      %a{:href => "#tabs-1"}
        %div{:class=>"ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"} New User
    %li
      %a{:href => "#tabs-2"}
        %div{:class=>"ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"} Existing User
  #tabs-1
    I am a new user
  #tabs-2
    I am an existing user
```

NOTE: this code works perfectly when it is ALL in the layout. But when I move the second chunk of code from my layout into my view, it stops working.

I thought views are external but functionally identical to their layouts. What exactly do I have to do to get these tabs working properly? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you mention a partial in your question title but make no mention of one in your question?

Comment: Sam, sorry for the confusion... I meant to differentiate between having all the code in one view as opposed to putting the javascript in a separate layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference. Make sure that you're replacing the exact contents of the second block with `= yield`. Check the HTML generated in both scenarios. When the second block is moved to a view only whitespace should differ.